# Spring Cloud Stream - programmatic publishing

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I'm wondering if a stream source could be invoked instead of being polled.
My source would be like this (won't work) :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class ServiceApplication {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private PersonsRepository dao;

    @GetMapping("/send")
    public String sendMessage() {
        this.sendVoter("foo");
        return "VOTER SENT";
    }

    @SentTo(Source.OUTPUT)
    private Person sendVoter(String name) {
        logger.warn("Sending...");
        return dao.findByFirstname(name);
    }
}
```

To make it start, I had to code that :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class ServiceApplication {
...
    @GetMapping("/send")
    public String sendMessage() {
        this.sendVoter();
        return "VOTER SENT";
    }

    @InboundChannelAdapter(Source.OUTPUT)
    private Person sendVoter() {
        logger.warn("Sending...");
        return dao.findByFirstname("foo");
    }
}
```

But the source is starting right away. It's not programmatically triggered.
Do I have to use ApplicationEventPublisher or is this for Spring Cloud Bus applications only ? Any other tip I can't think about ?
Thanks for any light

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject the channel or the interface directly and call it from your controller method in a similar way to this: http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Brooklyn.SR2/reference/htmlsingle/#_injecting_the_bound_interfaces

Comment: Right. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Autowired Source source; source.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(msg).build()‌​);

Comment: So, what about the SendTo annotation? what is it for, only processors?